# Return value of librosa.effect.Split is strange

Tags: python, librosa

As titled, the result of this function is not logical and I don't understand what the function is doing.

For example, here is some reproducible code:

```
#load sample audio
filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
audio, sr = librosa.load(filename)

#get intervals which are non-silent
inter_20 = librosa.effects.split(audio, top_db=20)
inter_5 = librosa.effects.split(audio, top_db=5)

#create audio
above_20 = np.zeros(audio.shape)
above_5 = np.zeros(audio.shape)

for i in inter_20:
    start,end = i
    above_20[start:end]=audio[start:end]

for j in inter_5:
    start,end = j
    above_5[start:end]=audio[start:end]

#plot them out:
plt.figure(figsize=[15,3]) #figure 1
plt.plot(audio)
plt.plot(above_5,color='red')
plt.title('Audio above 5 dB')

plt.figure(figsize=[15,3]) #figure 2
plt.plot(audio)
plt.plot(above_20,color='red')
plt.title('Audio above 20 dB')
```

you can see from here:
for figure 1, which is audio above 5dB:

[image: audio above 5db]

for figure 2, which is audio above 20dB:

[image: audio above 20db]

**How can it be that audio above 20dB is more than audio above 5dB?**
To me this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you trying to denoise some audio? As in, you have some audio where a person is speaking and there is some background noise that you want to remove? I don't think there is anything wrong with librosa's `split()` return value

Comment: @Ahmad Moussa, what i want to do is to remove silence...i have some real data and it contains several silent segments, i want to use this function to remove them...

Comment: @BarCodeReader, did you solve your problem? Cause I have a similar one. I have a speech of a person and want to remove all the long pauses between sentences. Struggling with librosa right now and eventually winded up out here

Comment: from below's answer, seems there is a default top_db value K in librosa, for example, K = 15. now when you set top_db = 5, this does not mean below 5db sounds, this means below K - 5 = 10db sounds will be treated as silence. I think this K value can be set in librosa. But TBH, the function here is a bit confusing and misleading.

Comment: I agree...this top_db is quite confusing term. Basically anything below (max_db-top_db) values are removed by treating as "silence" as explained by Pieter21 below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation at: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.effects.split.html

```
top_db:number > 0

  The threshold (in decibels) **below** reference to consider as silence
```

I think top_db:20 means everything below (TOP - 20dB) instead of just 20dB is considered silence.

And there will be more above TOP - 20dB than TOP - 5dB. It also could explain your pictures.

Comment: top_db=20 means below 20 db is silence and librosa will remove it. so, librosa will remove more if we use 20 db instead of 5db, then it means for 20 db, we obtain less non-silent audio...but from my graph above, we get more when top_db=20 is set.

Comment: correct me if i understand the doc incorrectly...really thanks

Comment: @BarCodeReader, I think it means 20dB below the reference value. The reference value can be set or is the maximum value by default. If I understand the documentation correctly. And it would explain your observation.

Comment: ok I see your point. I will test by using amplitude_to_db function or similar functions to check if it is really like that